excel vba styles.add.VALUE What does it do
I have been writing a macro to define a custom style and I cannot find what the following does:
ActiveWorkbook. styles.add.value
I thought it might allow me to set an initial value (like "x") in any cell that I use the style, but no such luck yet.
I understand that it would be MUCH easier to just import the style, but my computer is restricted by my employer.
Sub testasdfasdf()

With ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add("05 - Highlight 2")

.IncludeNumber = False

.IncludeFont = True

.IncludeAlignment = False

.IncludeBorder = False

.IncludePatterns = True

.IncludeProtection = False

.IncludeNumber = False

.Interior.Color = True

    .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    .WrapText = True
.value = True

/or I tried this
/. Value= "x" 
  
End With
End Sub
 


It's a read-only property. Try Debug.Print .Value within With caluses. Microsoft documentation:

Style.Value property (Excel)

